# Enable Internet (Wi-Fi) and Intranet (Ethernet) to work at the same time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ethernet

**EDIT: OS is Windows 7.**

I have seen a couple of threads about this, but I am so limited in my networking knowledge that I have been unable to get those solutions to work for me.

I am trying to connect to an intranet so that I can navigate to internal sites (such as Sharepoint, etc.), but I also need to be able to access my internet over a Wi-Fi connection, which is a 3G Mi-Fi.

What's currently happening is that, when I have the ethernet cable plugged in and Wi-Fi on at the same time, my internet works, but I cannot access the intranet. And it is really a huge pain to switch between the two.

My network details are below (not sure what other details would be needed?):

Wireless:

```
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.102 (preferred)
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 192.168.1.1
```

Wired:

```
Default Gateway: 172.23.42.1
IPv4 Address: 172.23.42.165 (preferred)
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 172.24.130.12
```

Please advise.

Thanks and regards,
Amy

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to manipulate your routing table. Since you do not state your OS, I cannot give you the exact commands, but basically what you need to do is:

1. Have only one default gateway, via your wifi. If it does not exist, create it; if there is a default gateway of the intranet connection delete this one, and create the one via the wifi.
2. Leave all other routes as they are.

To find out how to do it, just Google *How to change default gateway in Your_Operating_System*.

If you make an error, nothing to worry about: turn the pc off, and back, and the error has disappeared.

Comment: Annoying part here is, it dosen't look like the output of windows or linux. I don't have an OS X system to check

Answer (score 2):

You should not have a default gateway on the wired connection. There is no gateway to anything on that network.